# Hi I am trying to create a e commerce app UI design like the image below

Tags: android, e-commerce, cardview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvvfp.png)

I have a activity and i have to display multiple fragments cards as shown in the below image.How do i organize layouts.
Please help me how to achieve the below design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a view pager at the place where your images re being shown if you want to change them on swipe. Otherwise you can just put an image view and a text view to show the data of first item and replace the image and text on the imageview and textview one by one for all the items whenever you need. Let's say you can change the items after a certain time by using "TimerTask()".

This is the solution for that highlighted blue part. If I am not sounding appropriate then explain your question a little so I can help you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Its helps me.